# React unit test case for a component having a LInk

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, react-redux, jestjs

I am trying to write a unit test case for a component which has a `Link`

So, My component is like ,

```
 import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

    <div className="col-sm-4">
                    <Link to="create-job/new" style={{ textDecoration: 'none'}}><button type='button' className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block button-container">Create New Job</button></Link>
                </div>
export default withRouter(JobNotFound);
```

Now, what I did is ,

```
import JobNotFound from '../JobNotFound';
import { Link } from 'react-router';


describe('JobNotFound Component test cases', () => {

    it("renders JobNotFound Component successfully", () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(
            <JobNotFound />
        );
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    it("simulate the click event on Button", () => {
        const onButtonClick = sinon.spy();
        const wrapper = shallow(<JobNotFound />);
        expect(wrapper.find('Link').prop('to')).to.be.equal('/create-job/new');
    });
})
```

So, Here I am not getting that `Link` element. 
Can any one help me wit this ?

Comment: try to remove the quotes around `wrapper.find('Link')`, so - `wrapper.find(Link)`

Comment: TypeError: Enzyme::Selector expects a string, object, or Component Constructor

Comment: What version of enzyme are you using?

Comment: Ah that's because you're rendering the component wrapped with `withRouter`. What if you do `const wrapper = shallow(<JobNotFound />).dive();` and then expect to find the link component, does that work?

Comment: Invariant Violation: You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From react-router's official documents:

> If you try to unit test one of your components that renders a < Link >
>   or a < Route >, etc. you’ll get some errors and warnings about context.
>   While you may be tempted to stub out the router context yourself, we
>   recommend you wrap your unit test in a < StaticRouter > or a <
>   MemoryRouter >.

This is the reason why you're getting the error:

```
You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>
```

While testing link components, you should wrap them in one of these routers.

For example:

```
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
const wrapper = shallow(<MemoryRouter>
<JobNotFound/>
<MemoryRouter/>);
```

Also, since you're reaching the child components, try using `mount` rather than `shallow`.

**Update:**

The following test passed for me.

```
import { Link,MemoryRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

    test('simulate the click event on Button', () => {

      const onButtonClick = sinon.spy();
      const wrapper = mount(<Router><JobNotFound /></Router>);
      expect(wrapper.find(Link)).toBeTruthy();
      expect(wrapper.find('Link').prop('to')).toEqual('create-job/new');
    });
```

Comment: Hey could you give some link where I can find all the methods that I can call on expect like toEqual or toBetruthy ?

Comment: thanks a lot. If you have some time could you please check this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54624430/react-test-case-for-the-button-disabled-or-not-on-the-basis-of-state-value

Answer (score 1):

That is because of the withRouter wrapper on top of the actual component.

You need to do this

```
const wrapper = shallow(<JobNotFound.WrappedComponent />);
```

This will shallow render the actual component.