# React Test case for the button disabled or not on the basis of state value

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to write the test cases for the buttons enable or disable.

```
<button type="button" id="addBtn" className={`btn border-0 create-job-btn ${enabled ? 'add-btn' : 'jd-button'}`} disabled={!enabled} >Add/Paste Jd</button>
<span className="pl-1 pr-1"> or </span>
<button type="button" id="uploadBtn" className={`btn border-0 create-job-btn ${enabled ? "upload-btn" : "jd-button"}`} disabled={!enabled} >Upload Jd File</button>
```

Now, what I tried is,

```
it('should have buttons', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<SelectCriteraNewJob />);
        expect(wrapper.find('button#addBtn')).toBeTruthy();
        expect(wrapper.find('button#uploadBtn')).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

Now Here,

```
const enabled = (!!selectedTechnology && selectedTechnology.length > 0) && (!!userCompany && userCompany.length > 0)
```

So, I am confused in writting the test cases for the buttons `enable and disable`.

So, can any one help me with this ? Thanks.

Comment: you can spy the objects selectedTechnology and userCompany and check it

Comment: are     selectedTechnology and     userCompany stored in your state? or is it passed as a prop or given as a const?

Comment: this are stored in a state

Comment: const { selectedTechnology } = this.state;
    const { userCompany } = this.props;
    const enabled = (!!selectedTechnology && selectedTechnology.length > 0) && (!!userCompany && userCompany.length > 0)

Comment: @Harvey this is the way I have used

Comment: @Harvey Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: Hi ganesh, no nothing missing, sorry couldn't answer was very busy with work past week. Will attempt to answer in a bit :)

Comment: Okay no problem. Thanks for this :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observing what your component renders, there seems to be three things to test:

1. It should render 2 buttons as children
2. When are these buttons enabled or disabled
3. classNames of these components

The primary test case is the 'enabled' case. Testing classNames or not is up to you, it's mostly not necessary to test inline styles or css classes.

It seems that both buttons are disabled if `userCompany` and/or `selectedTechnology` aren't given, and if they're both given, both buttons are enabled.

You can observe the 'disabled' prop of the html buttons, according to the state & prop you have given to the component.

```
const wrapper = shallow(<SelectCriteraNewJob userCompany='Some Company' />);

it('SelectCriteraNewJob should render two buttons as children', () => {
    expect(wrapper.childAt(0).type()).toEqual('button');
    // expect(wrapper.childAt(1).type()).toEqual('span'); if you want to, not necessary to test
    expect(wrapper.childAt(2).type()).toEqual('button');
});

describe('If technology and company are not empty, both buttons are enabled. Otherwise disabled.',() => {
    expect(wrapper.find('button#addBtn')).toBeTruthy();
    expect(wrapper.find('button#uploadBtn')).toBeTruthy();

    test('Company and technology given', () => {
        wrapper.setState({selectedTechnology: 'React'});
        const addBtn = wrapper.find('button#addBtn').prop('disabled');
        const uploadBtn = wrapper.find('button#uploadBtn').prop('disabled');
        expect(addBtn).toBeFalsy();
        expect(uploadBtn).toBeFalsy();
    });
    test('Only technology given', () => {
        wrapper.setProps({userCompany:''});
        const addBtn = wrapper.find('button#addBtn').prop('disabled');
        const uploadBtn = wrapper.find('button#uploadBtn').prop('disabled');
        expect(addBtn).toBeTruthy();
        expect(uploadBtn).toBeTruthy();
    });
    test('Only company given', () => {
        wrapper.setState({selectedTechnology:''});
        wrapper.setProps({userCompany:'Some Company'});
        const addBtn = wrapper.find('button#addBtn').prop('disabled');
        const uploadBtn = wrapper.find('button#uploadBtn').prop('disabled');
        expect(addBtn).toBeTruthy();
        expect(uploadBtn).toBeTruthy();
    });
    test('Neither are given', () => {
        wrapper.setState({selectedTechnology:''});
        wrapper.setProps({userCompany:''});
        const addBtn = wrapper.find('button#addBtn').prop('disabled');
        const uploadBtn = wrapper.find('button#uploadBtn').prop('disabled');
        expect(addBtn).toBeTruthy();
        expect(uploadBtn).toBeTruthy();
        expect(wrapper.find('button.jd-button')).toHaveLength(2); //optional, test css class name
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay so this way we can use the state values in the test case. Thanks a lot not just for the answer but also you taught me a new thing. So, this way I can test the component which are using the local state. Now what if the value for user company is coming from my reducer using the mapStateToProps in the same component

Comment: I haven't done much testing with react + redux together, only tested them seperately for unit testing. but this blog might help you  https://jsramblings.com/2018/01/15/3-ways-to-test-mapStateToProps-and-mapDispatchToProps.html

Comment: I am always getting this error. Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.